# figure before, not after #Discussion - R Markdown

Tags: position, r-markdown, figure

I am having an issue positioning a figure.

My header:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
\newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
```

Some of my R Markdown code:

````
\newpage
\blandscape
```{r finaltable1_1, echo=FALSE}
table1_1
```
\elandscape

\newpage
\blandscape
```{r figone, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, out.width='100%', fig.align='center', fig.cap='description.'}
knitr::include_graphics('./images/figure2.pdf')
```
\elandscape

\newpage
```{r figresults, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, out.width='100%', fig.align='center', fig.cap='description.'}
knitr::include_graphics('./images/figure3.pdf')
```

\newpage
# Discussion
````

figure3 should go before Discussion, but it is showing after, any ideas about what might be happening?

Comment: Your figures in .pdf?

Comment: Thanks @manro yes. I noticed that when I have a small table and after that I have \newpage # Discussion, the "Discussion" section starts on the page of the small table, not in a new one. Any ideas?

Comment: I'll see. Wait a moment.

Comment: Yes, I see this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can solve your problem by:

**a) reducing the pic's width in this chunk:**

````
```{r figresults, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, out.width='70%', fig.align='center', fig.cap='description.'}
knitr::include_graphics('pic.pdf')
```
````

**b) using another constructions:**

```
![My piccy-pic](pic.pdf){width=90%}
```

or

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{pic.pdf}
\caption{I'm here}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot @manro!!